# Colours - R,G,B values. Making a colour appear "lighter" to the human eye. Can someone explain this to me please?

Tags: colors

Just a short explanation how I came to this question. I have a ruby module which is basically a hash that gives me HTML "colours", like "slateblue", and gives me back an Array that holds the R,G,B values, like [106, 90, 205] for slateblue.

I googled how to make these R,G,B values into a lighter colour (for mouse cursor on hover effect), and several people told other people when they had a similar problem to just increase the R,G,B values. My current solution, which is a hack, is to add to the R,G,B values, like +20 (capped at 255), and then convert this into a hexstring #FF0000 something.

This seems to work okish but here is the thing now - I have absolutely no understanding about why this works.

Is it so that the 0 always denotes the lowest value of R/G/B and 255 the highest? If so, why is it capped at 255 and not at, don't know, 1024 or some other arbitrary number?

Comment: Did you read e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB?  (A quick "find" on that page will reveal the significance of 255.)

Answer (score 1):

Using 8-bits per color channel - one each for red, green, and blue - yields a large number of colors (2^24 or 16777216), and is sufficient to be used in most applications.  Note that there *are* other color formats with higher precision though.

0 is used for black, while 255 (the maximum stored in 8-bits) denotes "full-on" color.

Adding a specific number to each channel moves the entire color toward (255, 255, 255), or White.  If you would like to be more exact in your lightening of the color, you might try converting your RGB color to HSL, doing your addition to the light component only, then converting back to RGB.

You can start research of HSL here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV